# How do I pass value from one function to another?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, core-location

I'm making a location app in which I store my location on FireBase, I get my current coordinates in a function..but how do I send those coordinates to another function that stores them online.

Here is my code:

```
var latPass: Double!
var longPass: Double!

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    var location=locations[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan=MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    var myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion=MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    latPass=location.coordinate.latitude
    longPass=location.coordinate.longitude

}

func post(){

    let lat=latPass
    let long=longPass

    let post : [String: Double]=["lat":lat, "long":long]
    let dataBaseRef=FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    dataBaseRef.child("Location").childByAutoId().setValue(post)

}
```

my **latPass** & **longPass** are the coordinates that I want to pass to `post()`

How can I do it ? Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared them globally in your class so you are able to access them everywhere, as you have done now. No need to create additional variables.

```
func post() {
    let post : [String: Double]=["lat":latPass, "long":longPass]
    let dataBaseRef=FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    dataBaseRef.child("Location").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
}
```

Otherwise you could set parameters in your post function:

```
func post(lat: Double, long: Double) {
    let post : [String: Double]=["lat":lat, "long":long]
    let dataBaseRef=FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    dataBaseRef.child("Location").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
}
```

To call post now:

```
post(lat: 11.000, long: 12.000)
```

**Update:**
Update your `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` to this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // if you pass this guard, then you have a valid loction
    guard let latitude = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude, let longitude = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude else { return }
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan=MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion=MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    latPass = latitude
    longPass = longitude
    // Call post here because now you have valid a location
    post()
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `nil` when I print `latPass` in my `post()`

Comment: @NaveenSaini, check the update. Update that function.